invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
Today when I add a new kubenretes(v1.30.0) node into cluster, the new nodes shows error:
invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem

in the new node I am using containerd, seems could not found the image filesystem size? this is the lsblk  command output:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/containerd# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
vda    254:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─vda1 254:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─vda2 254:2    0  191M  0 part /boot/efi
└─vda3 254:3    0 39.8G  0 part /

this is the containerd version info:
root@iZhp33cq6mvrjo8mzatgrmZ:/etc/containerd# containerd --version
containerd github.com/containerd/containerd 1.6.20~ds1 1.6.20~ds1-1+b1

am I missing some configuation with the new nodes? the new node's pods are always waiting. what should I do to fixed this issue?
